# Cannot configure Apache to parse PHP files

Tags: php, apache, lampp

I have installed xampp in linux. And then I have updated the php.ini file like removed the ; before some libraries.

If i type localhost/test.php then that php file is downloading instead of execution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893714/installed-xampp-on-linux-but-it-now-just-downloads-php-files-instead-of-displa

The problem associated with the above url is same. I have tried the solutions for the above problem.But did not get solved.

Any body can help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that you have installed libapache2-mod-php5, if you are using ubuntu, open a terminal and go to /etc/apache2/mod-available and locate php5.conf and php5.load
If you dont have this module you cant load php files. You can check this page https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/php5.html